# Boolean Simplification for Kmap

Tags: boolean-algebra

**Diclaimer:** This is not a homework assignment, it's a practice sheet that already has answers provided and is not graded in any way, however the steps are not shown hence the question.

I'm having issues converting the following expression into one suitable for Kmaps

F= C . (AB)' + B . D . (AC)' + A.C'.D'

The ' notating the inverse.
I understand the expression has to be converted into a sum of products to be used in a karnaugh map however the expression I simplified to was not correct.

I ended up with the following:

C'A + C'B + BD'A + BD'C + A'C + A'B

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We note that:
\begin{align*}
F
&= C(AB)' + BD(AC)' + AC'D' \\
&= C(A' + B') + BD(A' + C') + AC'D' &\text{by DeMorgan's Law}\\
&= A'C + B'C + A'BD + BC'D + AC'D' &\text{by Distributivity and Commutativity}
\end{align*}